# App deploys (according to dashboard) but keep getting "Welcome to nginx"

Tags: appharbor

I have an app stored on Bitbucket.  I hooked it up to AppHarbor, and, according to the AppHarbor dashboard, the app builds and deploys successfully.
When I try to go to the application, I end up at "http://odetofood.apphb.com/" (as expected), but this is the content:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.

The app was deployed successfully ~9hrs ago.
Any ideas on what is going wrong?
Thanks, AppHarbor looks like a very useful facility...

Comment: Looks like the site is up now. Please consider posting an answer descibing how you solved the problem.

Comment: @Number8 how did you solved it?

Comment: @knerd  Sorry, mate, I haven't looked at this in many months.  It was a test that we lost interest in...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I realized I needed to clear my browser cache. So either open the page in a new browser, or clear the cache. Hope this helps someone else.